# Host '172.23.0.9' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: java, spring, docker

Hiho

Spring Settings

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3306/vetdb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root  
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jmx.default-domain=TierarztDatenController
endpoints.jmx.uniquie-names=true
```

Docker Compose

```
  vetdb:
    container_name: vetdb
    hostname: vetdb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --innodb-flush-method=O_DSYNC --innodb-use-native-aio=0 --log_bin=ON
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${VET_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${VET_DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${VET_DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
#      - "${VET_DB_PATH}/mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
      - "${VET_DB_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "${VET_DB_PATH}/mysql-log:/var/log/mysql"
```

.env

```
VET_DB_PATH=./dockervolumes/microservices/VET/db
VET_DB_NAME=vetdb
VET_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
VET_DB_PASSWORD=root

Exception: `java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '172.23.0.9' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"`
```

i added `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'` to allow everyone to connect to the db but it didnt work
i tried to use a `config-file.cnf` containing `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` but it didnt work

funny thing is everything worked well before i restarted the container today and i didnt change this service in 3 days

i tried see if name/password = root work

```
$ docker exec -it vetdb bash
root@vetdb:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

but root without password works (inside the container)

```
root@vetdb:/# mysql -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 21
Server version: 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~bionic-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

if i just remove `spring.datasource.password=root`
or set it to `spring.datasource.password=`
then it results in the same exception

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like mysql is ignoring all the environment variables i set, because the db i specified doesnt exist either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i changed the environment variables to this

```html
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${VET_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=${VET_DB_NAME}"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%"
```

and deleted everything rerun it and it worked

```html
docker-compose down
docker rm -f $(docker container ls -aq)
docker-compose rm -v
docker volume prune
docker system prune
rm dockerdockervolumes/ -rf
```

and it worked